# Simple 3-line browser extension - tons of warnings for no reason? No debugging possible

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, javascript-debugger

I just tried to write an incredibly simple browser extension. It simply displays a github cookie:

background-script.js

```
browser.cookies.get({url:"https://github.com/",name:"logged_in"})
.then(console.log)
.catch(console.error)
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "description": "cookie-test",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "cookie-test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "*://github.com/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background-script.js"]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Why do I get these weird warnings? It doesn't make any sense to me:

[image]

```
19:48:57.788 Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome.manifest'.
19:48:57.947 1484419737947  addons.xpi  WARN    Bootstrap state is invalid (missing add-ons: C:\Users\Admin\Projects\WebExtensions\Cookie-Test)
19:48:58.006 Warning: attempting to write 5994 bytes to preference extensions.xpiState. This is bad for general performance and memory usage. Such an amount of data should rather be written to an external file. This preference will not be sent to any content processes.
19:48:58.021 Warning: ‘nsIOService::NewChannel()’ deprecated, please use ‘nsIOService::NewChannel2()’  bootstrap.js:51:16
19:48:58.324 unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  modifyheaders-service.js:169:9
19:48:58.776 1484419738776  addons.webextension.jid0-XWJxt5VvCXkKzQK99PhZqAn7Xbg@jetpack    WARN    Loading extension 'jid0-XWJxt5VvCXkKzQK99PhZqAn7Xbg@jetpack': Reading manifest: Error processing minimum_chrome_version: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
19:48:58.776 1484419738776  addons.webextension.jid0-XWJxt5VvCXkKzQK99PhZqAn7Xbg@jetpack    WARN    Loading extension 'jid0-XWJxt5VvCXkKzQK99PhZqAn7Xbg@jetpack': Reading manifest: Error processing author: An unexpected property was found in the WebExtension manifest.
19:49:02.423 TypeError: aPopupMenu.triggerNode is null[Learn More]  browser.js:7598:5
19:49:06.426 Object { name: "logged_in", value: "yes", domain: ".github.com", hostOnly: false, path: "/", secure: true, httpOnly: true, session: false, storeId: "firefox-default", expirationDate: 2099507241 }  (unknown)
```

I simply clicked the highlighted debug button and made a screenshot of the console that appeared:

[image]

Also, why can't I see my background-script.js in the Debugger?

[image]

---

**Edit:**
After disabling all extensions, dictionaries, plugins, etc, some warnings disappear. So why the heck are other extensions printing to the console of MY own extension? How do I prevent that? Here are the remaining warnings:

[image]

```
22:24:14.215 Could not read chrome manifest 'file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome.manifest'.
22:24:14.421 Warning: attempting to write 6006 bytes to preference extensions.xpiState. This is bad for general performance and memory usage. Such an amount of data should rather be written to an external file. This preference will not be sent to any content processes.
22:24:33.099 XrayWrapper denied access to property Symbol.toPrimitive (reason: object is not safely Xrayable). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Xray_vision for more information. Note that only the first denied property access from a given global object will be reported. script.js:2352:4
22:25:04.162 Object { name: "logged_in", value: "yes", domain: ".github.com", hostOnly: false, path: "/", secure: true, httpOnly: true, session: false, storeId: "firefox-default", expirationDate: 2099507241 }  (unknown)
```

I also noticed that after some minutes more stuff appears:

```
22:27:03.842 Key event not available on some keyboard layouts: key=“c” modifiers=“accel,alt”  browser.xul
22:27:03.842 Key event not available on some keyboard layouts: key=“r” modifiers=“accel,alt”  browser.xul
22:27:03.842 Key event not available on some keyboard layouts: key=“i” modifiers=“accel,alt,shift”  browser.xul
22:27:34.893 Content Security Policy: Directive ‘frame-src’ has been deprecated. Please use directive ‘child-src’ instead.  (unknown)
22:27:35.524 Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. disco-4148d229e50ce51a9c0d.js:169:10199
22:27:35.677 Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead. disco-4148d229e50ce51a9c0d.js:169:10199
22:29:44.177 TypeError: this._recipeManager is null[Learn More]  LoginManagerParent.jsm:77:9
```

The sources in the debugger are still empty btw.

Comment: While the images help, please copy and paste the actual text of the errors as **text** ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)). Images do not allow us to copy & paste the code/errors for testing. In addition, images of your code/error do not permit it to be searched based on the code/error contents. In general, code/errors in text format >>> code/errors as an image >>>>> nothing.  Images should only be used, in addition to text format, if having the image adds something. In this case they would be fine in addition to text.

Comment: For instance, if you had the errors as text, I would copy and paste them into an answer and explain where each one is coming from. Without having them in you Question as text (which would have just been a copy-&-paste), I would need to either recreate them, or type each one out. That is a lot more work.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Done.